# How to avoid artefacts when masking an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pytorch, autoencoder

I am develop an autoencoder to detect anomalies in images. In a preprocessing step, I start with resizing the image and apply a black mask to the image to end up with a round shape. Example code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# center_coords - x & y coordinate of the circle
# RADIUS - radius of the circle

img = cv2.imread(img_path)
(height, width, channels) = img.shape
circle_mask = np.zeros((height, width, channels), dtype=np.uint8)
circle_mask = cv2.circle(circle_mask,center_coord, RADIUS,(255, 255, 255),-1)
       
circle_mask = cv2.bitwise_and(img, circle_mask)
cropped = circle_mask[center_coord[1]-RADIUS: center_coord[1]+RADIUS,
                      center_coord[0]-RADIUS: center_coord[0]+RADIUS]

cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(dst_image), cropped)
```

Now I am using the `torchvisions` RandomRotation with 360° degrees for augmentation

```py
from torchvision import transforms

img_transforms= transforms.Compose([
                    transforms.RandomRotation(360),
                    transforms.ToTensor(), 
                    ])
```

After checking the reconstruction error of the images, it appeared that the corners and the masked area resulted in the pixels with the highest reconstruction error.

Heatmap with reconstruction errors

[image]

Used Colormap: `red = high intensity!`

[image]

Probably the high reconstruction error results from artefacts in the training images. Is there a better way to mask the images to avoid these artefacts or could these be a result of the random rotation augmentation from *torchvision*?

Comment: are you saving your training samples as jpeg or any other lossy compression? What's used during training? 0:normal and >0:abnormal? Maybe you can change that to 0...50:normal and 51..255:abnormal? I think neither from masking nor from rotation there should appear artifacts like in the reconstruction

Comment: Im saving the images as Jpeg after the preprocessing step (Resizing, Masking).

What do you exactly mean with 0 = normal? Do you mean the pixel values? 
The structure in the image is important, so iht wouldn't be enough to mark a specific interval of pixel values as anomaly.

Comment: ok, didnt read well. Thought you are trying to train the masks, but instead you are really masking the images. Is the training handling masked pixels differently? If yes, try to avoid lossy compression or use another thresholding after reading the images, to overcome jpeg artifacts at the mask border. What exactly are the masks for? Why do you mask the images?

Comment: Can you sare your code of how you calculate the reconstruction error? If it is relative to the pixel intensity, even small absolute deviations will lead to high relative values in the masked region.